# `ListPlot` with `Association` as input

Tags: plotting, associations

It seems `ListPlot` will somehow drop the trailing list of `Association`s when the `Association` label names are different (here I use three *different labels*: **Sin**, **Cos** and **Tan**):

```
asscTest0 = Table[Association[{"t" -> t, ToString[fun] -> fun[t]}], {fun, {Sin, Cos, Tan}}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/3}]; 
ListPlot[asscTest0,Joined -> True]
(*error message: ListPlot::lpn: {{{0.,0.},{1.0472,0.866025},{2.0944,0.866025},{3.14159,0.},{4.18879,-0.866025},{5.23599,-0.866025},{6.28319,0.}},{},{}} is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers.*)
```

However, if the `Association` label names are kept **the same** (i.e., "fun"), `ListPlot` can work:

```
asscTest1 = Table[Association[{"t" -> t, "fun" -> fun[t]}], {fun, {Sin, Cos}}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/3}]
```

Should this be considered as a bug? Or I missed something?

Comment: Hi @kglr, that's not the point of my question: I used `ToString[fun]` intentionally to create different labels, which can lead to the errors shown in the question.

Comment: sunt05, i realized that after posting the comment:)

Comment: thanks all the same for your attention, @kglr! The question was actually raised when using `ListPlot` in a `Dataset`, where the column names are different. Then I realised the issue resides in the way that `ListPlot` picks up data.

Comment: Your use of `ListPlot` + `Association` does not quite match any of the documented paradigms, so it's hard to be sure if it's a bug.  I'd say it should succeed, and WRI should consider it a bug. There's no need to use the keys of the first association for the others, which it seems to do: `Trace[ListPlot[asscTest0, Joined -> True], _Missing]`

Comment: it's true that such `ListPlot`+`Association` combination is NOT "official"; however, such operations are allowed in `Dataset` queries, which are the actual source of my question. And you can see such operation of `ListPlot` is also suggested in the guide page of `Association` http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html, though the help of `ListPlot` is not updated accordingly.

Comment: I don't see where such a combination is suggested in the guide.  I see several combinations of `ListPlot` and `Association` illustrated in the docs for `ListPlot`, though. But I think your code should work; whether we want to call it a bug or a missing feature, I think you should report it to WRI.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2. Just reported this to WRI.

Answer (score 2):

Though not documented, the following works :

```
asscTest3=
Association[
    Table[ToString[fun]-> 
        Table[
            Association[{"t" -> t, "anything" -> fun[t]}],
            {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/3}
             ],
         {fun, {Sin, Cos, Tan}}
         ]
     ];

asscTest3 //N

ListPlot[asscTest3,Joined -> True]
```

> <|"Sin" -> {<|"t" -> 0., 
>       "anything" -> 0.|>, <|"t" -> 1., "anything" -> 0.9|> ...},
>       "Cos" -> {<|"t" -> 0., 
>       "anything" -> 1.|>, <|"t" -> 1., "anything" -> 0.5|> ..},
>       "Tan" -> {<|"t" -> 0.`, 
>       "anything" -> 0.|>, <|"t" -> 1., "anything" -> 1.7|> ..}|>

[image]

Note that a legend has appeared. This legend corresponds to the option `PlotLegends -> "Expressions"` (or `"AllExpressions"`) which seems to be the default (at least on my version, 11.3). You can remove it whith `PlotLegends -> None`

Answer (score 1):

We could, theoretically, make this work, but I suspect that people then wouldn't like the result of

```
ListPlot[{
 Table[<|"a" -> i, "b" -> i^2|>, {i, 5}],
 Table[<|"b" -> i + 1, "a" -> i|>, {i, 5}]
 }]
```

Right now `ListPlot` consistently maps `"a"` to the $x$ coordinate and `"b"` to $y$.  Once `ListPlot` gives a meaning to a particular association key, it uses that for the rest of the evaluation.